# How to assign previous date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table A

```
+====+======+============+============+
| id | m_id |    s_dt    |    e_dt    |
+====+======+============+============+
|  2 |  101 | 2015-06-28 | 2059-12-31 |
+----+------+------------+------------+
| 10 |  101 | 2018-01-07 | 2059-12-31 |
+----+------+------------+------------+
```

When `id = 2`,I want to assign `e_dt = 2018-01-06` (i.e. 1 day prior to the `st_dt` of `id=10`).

How do i do that?

Comment: Add a few more rows of sample table data, and its expected result.

Comment: @user3183055 I've input some more sample data in an answer I've provided. Please let me know if adjustments need to be made.

Comment: @user3183055 - Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can try this:

```
SELECT id, s_dt , DATEADD(DAY,-1,LEAD(s_dt) OVER(ORDER BY id)) AS e_dt FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need information of two record in one record in a sequence order, So first prepare it in orderd sequence with CTE and ROW_NUMBER then join result with itself to arrange a record with next record in sequence:

```
with TA as
(select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by id) as rn,* from TableA)
select t1.id,t1.m_id,t1.s_dt,DATEADD(day, -1,t2.st_dt) as e_dt 
from TA t1 join TA t2 on t1.rn+1=t2.rn
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: @iBug; Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I would recommend using a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql), for example:

```
--use common table expression to sort the m_id and id into unique row numbers
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m_id, id) AS rowNum
    , *
    FROM TableA
    )
--Update the original table, using the row number + 1 
--(use the next row to determine the next s_dt) 
UPDATE tblA
SET tblA.e_dt = DATEADD(day, - 1, tblB.s_dt)
FROM cte tblA
INNER JOIN cte tblB ON tblA.rowNum + 1 = tblB.rowNum and tblA.m_id = tblB.m_id
```

In my example, you'll see that the `e_dt` when its the last/latest row for a corresponding `m_id`, will be your future date `2059-12-31`, because there is no row with a corresponding `s_dt` for it yet. Based on the way the columns are named, basically what I am saying is "There current run for this `m_id` has no "end date" **yet**... It is still running".

Also, you will see that this works even if the data was inserted into the table in non-sequential order. Meaning, an `m_id` with a different value 'could' very well be inserted in-between a pair of start and end dates for another `m_id`.

Results of test:

[image]

Code I used to test, with additional test values:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [m_id] [INT],
    [s_dt] [DATETIME],
    [e_dt] [DATETIME]
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA]
SELECT '101','2015-06-28','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '101','2018-01-07','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','2015-06-28','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','2016-05-07','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','2015-06-28','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','2017-01-07','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','2017-05-28','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '104','2018-01-07','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '103','2018-01-07','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '102','2018-06-28','2059-12-31' UNION ALL
SELECT '104','2018-01-24','2059-12-31'
GO

--verify data
SELECT * FROM TableA

--use common table expression to sort the m_id and id into unique row numbers
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m_id, id) AS rowNum
    , *
    FROM TableA
    )
--Update the original table, using the row number + 1 (use the next row to determine the next s_dt) 
UPDATE tblA
SET tblA.e_dt = DATEADD(day, - 1, tblB.s_dt)
FROM cte tblA
INNER JOIN cte tblB ON tblA.rowNum + 1 = tblB.rowNum and tblA.m_id = tblB.m_id

--verify
SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY m_id, id


--DROP TABLE dbo.[TableA]
```